# How do I solve this differential equation using sympy or py-pde?

Tags: python, numerical-methods, differential-equations, scientific-computing

I would like to solve the following inhomogeneous partial differential equation:

[image]

I have been reading the documentation for py-pde and figure I should make a 'ScalarField' object representing the RHS, but besides that implementing a custom pde seems difficult. I am restricting myself to python for a class I'm taking.

For background, I am solving for the wavefunction of a perturbed hydrogen atom. E is just a real number. Everything will be expressed in spherical coordinates.